Balancing multivariable functions in optimization
I heard that in the optimization of multivariable functions there is a kind of regularization of the variables in order to make the function more "balanced", like a circle in 2D for 2 variables. This would reduce the chance of overshooting some variables when taking a step in a given direction. I would like to study this but didn't find related topics in my text books. How this strategy is formally called? Any suggestion of books discussing it?
I also heard someting about the Jacobian in Newton's method playing this role. Is that correct?

Whitening transform?

I believe you are referring to Conjugate gradient method.
Conjugate gradient method is invented to overcome the zig-zag behavior of steepest descent, the main idea is to perform a linear transformation so that the ellipsoid is more symmetrical.

